# How to read a CSV Column with space in name using panda library in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So lets say I have a column in my csv file named "how are you" 
how can I read the contents of this column?
Right now I am changing the column name in csv file and running this, it works but how can I do it without changing anything in the csv file?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
x = df1.howareyou
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a column like this :

`x = df1["how are you"]`

Comment: @ech0 glad it helped ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

samutamm's answer definitely works.

However, if you like to access the columns using `dot` notation, you can replace the spaces with '_'. e.g:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
df.how_are_you
```